# Django Populating Table From Database

Tags: django, django-models

I can't get a table to populate with integers from database every time I click button (not really a button but with ajax inputs into db fine). Here is the code.

```
    Html:
          {% if past %}
            <table border="1">
              <thead>
                <th>Past</th>
              </thead>
              {% for nums in past %}
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ nums.numbers }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              {% endfor %}
            </table>
          {% else %}
            <p>error</p>
          {% endif %}

    Views.py:
    def main(request):
    
        prev_rng = 'X'
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            rolled_num = PastRng(numbers=request.POST['rngInput'])
            rolled_num.save()
    
            prev_rng = PastRng.objects.all()
    
    
        login_names = Players.objects.all()
    
        context_dict = {'past': prev_rng, 'names': login_names}
        print(context_dict)
    
        return render(request, 'main/rngmain.html', context=context_dict)

    urls.py:
    from django.urls import path
    from main import views
    
    app_name = 'main'
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('rules/', views.rules, name='rules'),
        path('main/', views.main, name='main'),
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
    ]

    main.models:
        class PastRng(models.Model):
            numbers = models.IntegerField(unique=False)
        
            def __int__(self):
                return self.numbers

onclick h1 with ajax to send to views.py and store in db (works fine):
    <div class="rng">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        function rngRotate(){
          var csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
          var rngRand = Math.random() * 100;
          var rngInput = Math.round(rngRand);
          document.getElementById("rngNum").textContent = rngInput;
          $.ajax({
            url: '/main/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'rngInput': rngInput,
                   'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
            }
          }).done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
          });
        }
      </script>
      <h1 id="rngNum" onclick="rngRotate();">100</h1>
      {% csrf_token %}
    </div>
```

Everything works fine accept the actual display of the database info in the table. Pretty sure views.py is the problem. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Can you show your form and its fields? If you don't have one, you will need one.

Comment: I don't have a form I used ajax with h1 in the code to input data into database. Which works fine. Everytime I click the h1 it generates a new number and stores fine. I have checked the admin. So the only problem I have is looping through the database and displaying in the html

Comment: Check the indentation on your views.py, all your code should be inside the if request.method == 'POST':

Comment: I tried a zillion different indenting ways and none of them worked.Nothing shows up, its not an error. It realizes there is something in the database and saved to 'past'. It  just doesn't render the table.